# Jquery show hidden table rows using SlideDown()

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have 3 rows in a table of which 1 row is visible and 2 are hidden.
I want to show the hidden rows when a button is clicked. Below is the html table and Jquery function but it does not run nor display any error.

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script> 
<table id="employee_grid" cellspacing="0">  
<tbody id="_editable_table">     
 <tr data-row-id="1" class="sum" name="data-row-id_1" id="data-row-id_1" style="display:visible;"> 
  <td align="center">1</td> 
  <td class="editable-col" contenteditable="true" col-index='1' oldVal ="Basic Salary">Basic Salary</td>
  <td amount class="editable-col" contenteditable="true" col-index='2' oldVal ="1000.00" onkeyup="CalculateMonthlySalary();">1000.00</td>
      </tr>        
 <tr data-row-id="2" class="sum" name="data-row-id_2" id="data-row-id_2" style="display:none;">    
  <td align="center">2</td> 
  <td class="editable-col" contenteditable="true" col-index='1' oldVal =""></td>
  <td amount class="editable-col" contenteditable="true" col-index='2' oldVal ="1000.00" onkeyup="CalculateMonthlySalary();"></td>
      </tr>         
 <tr data-row-id="3" class="sum" name="data-row-id_3" id="data-row-id_3" style="display:none;">    
  <td align="center">3</td>  
  <td class="editable-col" contenteditable="true" col-index='1' oldVal =""></td>
  <td amount class="editable-col" contenteditable="true" col-index='2' oldVal ="1000.00" onkeyup="CalculateMonthlySalary();"></td>
      </tr>       
 <tr><td colspan="3"><button onclick="AddItemRow();">Add New Row</button></td></tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

script goes here

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="JavaScript">
var iRowCounter = 3;
var iRowVisible = 1;
var iTotalRows = 3;


function AddItemRow() {
            $("#data-row-id_" + iRowVisible).slideDown(800);            
            iRowVisible++;
}

</script>
```

Comment: You forgot to add the script to your HTML page

Comment: You need to add `<script type="text/javascript" src=".....<location of the script with AddItemRow()....>`

Comment: what you mean ? the src file is there on top of the page. https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js

Comment: What you have on the top of the page is the `src` for JQuery, not for your script file. You need to add another one, with `src=<path to your js file>`

Comment: slideDown() is part of jquery which another src file you are referring to ?

Comment: `slideDown()` **is** part of JQuery, but `AddItemRow()` is not...

Comment: What is the name of the .JS that you have `AddItemRow()` in ?

Comment: Like all the others said, your HTML file is not connected to your script file. Add the tag and it will work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the problem was inside the page itself. There was nothing wrong with the function.
the"form" tag in the page was giving problem. After i remove it, it works fine.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that you forgot to add a script path to your HTML page.
`slideDown()` is part of JQuery, but `AddItemRow()` is not.

What you have on the top of the page is the src for JQuery, not for your script file. You need to add another one, with `src=<path to your js file>`, Like so:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="<location of the script with AddItemRow>"></script>
```